# How to clear the file name after file upload in Internet Explorer using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, html, angularjs

```
<input type="file" ng-model="myobj.file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect_filter($files)" id="fileButton" >
<button type="button" ng-click="start_Filter();" >Upload</button>
```

and my onFileSelect_filter() function goes like this,

```
$scope.onFileSelect_filter = function($files){
   ....
};
```

I want to clear the file name after i click the **Upload** button in Internet Explorer atleast.

This input box is not inside the form
Thanks in advance...!!!

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.myobj.file = null` or `$scope.myobj.file = ''`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, equating the bound `$scope` variables to empty string or null will not work in this case.

Although you can achieve it by 1 of the below mentioned ways.

**Method 1** :

You have to literally replace the html on the DOM on-click(on upload in your case) and revert it to how it was before upload. Like so..

```
 $scope.start_Filter = function(){
   // This is in the upload function post all your logic
   $("#fileButton").replaceWith("<input type='file' ng-model='myobj.file' ng-file-select='onFileSelect_filter($files)' id='fileButton' >").html();
};
```

*Note : You MUST use single-quotes instead of double-quotes for all the HTML attribute values inside the `replaceWith` function*

**Method 2** :

Alternatively you can easily clear the filename using JQuery. Like so..

```
$scope.start_Filter = function(){
   // This is in the upload function post all your logic
   $("#fileButton").val('');
};
```

One of these should work. Please try them and let me know if you face any troubles.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is : `angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null);`

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller, after file upload completed change the `myobj.file value.`

```
$scope.myobj.file = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the *$scope.myobj* `var`:

```
$scope.onFileSelect_filter = function($files){
    $scope.myobj.file = undefined;
};
```